# How to compose the expected JSON string response with my Java web service

Tags: java, json

Say I have to compose below **JSON** string response to a **HTTP get request**:

```
{
"filename": "100055_1_0920_082714_014"，  
"sfyc": "1", 
"rect": [                
            {"type1": ["1145", "1027", "1954", "1259"]},
            {"type2": ["1527", "788", "569", "418"]}, 
            {"type1": ["4053", "773", "915", "449"]}
        ]
}
```

I think if I want to compose the JSON string, I need a JSON Object(`{"type1": ["1145", "1027", "1954", "1259"]}`),wihch can be transformed from a Java Class which has a feild `type1` of type `List<String>`, and another Class for `type2`. Then *Gson* or *Jackson* can help in my case.

Problem is that I have more than 20 different types, so I don't think defining all of these Java classes is a good choice. So how can I have the wanted JSON String in a smart way?

---

**Note:**

Each type may appear more than once(like `type1` in my code) so `map` should not be the answer.

Comment: How do you obtain this json object ? by calling an external service ?

Comment: {"type1": ["1145", "1027", "1954", "1259"]} can be achieved through a Map<String,List<String>>

then map.put("type1", type1List);
       map.put("type2", type2List); etc
this map can then be converted using Jackson

Comment: Use a one class generic type for this with field of type List<String>

Comment: @Jebil Problem is that type1 can be appear for more than once. So does type2 and other types. Just imagine in an object detection task, there can be more than one object with `type1` detected.

Comment: @imprezzeb Can you give more details? Do I need to define Classes for all these types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a dto like

```
public class Dto {
        private String fileName;
        private Integer sfyc;
        private List<Map<String, List<String>>> rect;
      }
```

Try running the main method to verify

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import lombok.Data;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Dto dto = getDummy();
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(dto));
  }

  @Data
  public static class Dto {
    private String fileName;
    private Integer sfyc;
    private List<Map<String, List<String>>> rect;
  }

  public static Dto getDummy() {
    Dto dto = new Dto();

    dto.setFileName("100055_1_0920_082714_014");
    dto.setSfyc(1);
    List<String> type1List = List.of("1145", "1027", "1954", "1259");// of function for java 9 or newer
    List<String> type2List = List.of("1527", "788", "569", "418");
    List<String> type3List = List.of("4053", "773", "915", "449");
    List<Map<String, List<String>>> maps =
        List.of(
            Map.of("type1", type1List),
            Map.of("type2", type2List),
            Map.of("type1", type3List));
    dto.setRect(maps);
    return dto;
  }
}
```

it will produce an out put like

```
{
  "fileName": "100055_1_0920_082714_014",
  "sfyc": 1,
  "rect": [
    {
      "type1": [
        "1145",
        "1027",
        "1954",
        "1259"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type2": [
        "1527",
        "788",
        "569",
        "418"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type1": [
        "4053",
        "773",
        "915",
        "449"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks but map should not be the answer since each type may be used more than once.

Comment: @ZhaoGang each type will be in a different map as shown, hows that going to be an issue ?

Comment: I mean, there can be multiple JSON object for `type1`(so does other types) in the JSON Array. @Jebil

Comment: i just updated the answer @ZhaoGang is that what you mean ?

Comment: if you are looking for something like `{"type1":[],"type2":[],"type1":[]}` thats not possible with JSON rules, you cannot have a duplicate key @ZhaoGang

Comment: Yes. `type1` can appear more than onece. But I thought `map` cannot do this since it cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: its a list of map, not a single map.
each map will contain only one type @ZhaoGang

Comment: I updated the code in my post to clearify the question.@Jebil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200047/discussion-between-jebil-and-zhaogang).

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for this, is to use a map to store the custom types, So that we don't have to create a new class for each type. I was able to achieve this using following code.

POJO class.

```
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("filename")
private String filename;
@JsonProperty("sfyc")
private String sfyc;
@JsonProperty("rect")
private List<Map<String,List<String>>> rect;

@JsonProperty("filename")
public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}

@JsonProperty("filename")
public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

@JsonProperty("sfyc")
public String getSfyc() {
    return sfyc;
}

@JsonProperty("sfyc")
public void setSfyc(String sfyc) {
    this.sfyc = sfyc;
}


/**
 * @return the list
 */
@JsonProperty("rect")
public List<Map<String, List<String>>> getList() {
    return rect;
}

/**
 * @param list the list to set
 */
@JsonProperty("list")
public void setList(List<Map<String, List<String>>> rect) {
    this.rect = rect;
}
```

}

Main class to test this change.

```
public class TestJsonProblem {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    Example example = new Example();
    example.setFilename("Test");
    example.setSfyc("1");
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    map.put("type1", Arrays.asList("1145", "1027", "1954", "1259"));
    map.put("type2", Arrays.asList("1145", "1027", "1954", "1259"));
    map.put("type3", Arrays.asList("1145", "1027", "1954", "1259"));
    List<Map<String, List<String>>> list = new ArrayList();

    list.add(map);
    example.setRect(list);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonData = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(example);
    System.out.println(jsonData);
}
```

}

Output :

```
{
  "filename" : "Test",
  "sfyc" : "1",
  "rect" : [ {
             "type3" : [ "1145", "1027", "1954", "1259" ],
             "type2" : [ "1145", "1027", "1954", "1259" ],
             "type1" : [ "1145", "1027", "1954", "1259" ]
              } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks but map should not be the answer since each type may be used more than once.

Comment: @ZhaoGang If one type can appear more than once, how do you identify each type uniquely inside that element?

Comment: They are not unique ..  This JSON format is the result of an object detection task.  In a single picture, there may be more than one suggested locations for every object type...Now I guess I should do some class defnition work, or, I can manually modify the JSON string.

Comment: @ZhaoGang There is one solution , where you can use Pair class in Java which would allow duplicates. But you JSON might look bit different.                 ` {
  "filename" : "Test",
  "sfyc" : "1",
  "rect" : [ {
    "key" : "type1",
    "value" : [ "1145", "1027", "1954", "1259" ]`
  }, {
    "key" : "type2",
    "value" : [ "1145", "1027", "1954", "1259" ]
  }, {
    "key" : "type3",
    "value" : [ "1145", "1027", "1954", "1259" ]
  }, {
    "key" : "type1",
    "value" : [ "1145", "1027", "1954", "1259" ]
  } ]
}`

Answer (score -1):

```
{
    "filename": "100055_1_0920_082714_014",
    "sfyc": "1",
    "rect": [
        {
            "type1": [
                "1145",
                "1027",
                "1954",
                "1259"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type2": [
                "1527",
                "788",
                "569",
                "418"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type3": [
                "4053",
                "773",
                "915",
                "449"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and use this as Web site 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/